# mySql fetch array ignore null value

Tags: php, mysql

Here i am populating my dropdowns with database fields using php
my code follows,

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$series1 .= "<option id='Series1' value='" . $row['Series'] ."'>" . $row['Series'] ."             </option>";
}
```

after fetching i echo it to html

```
<select id="Series1"  onchange="changeVal('Series1')">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
        <?php echo $series1 ?>
</select>
```

my problem is i have some null values in the database field, i don't want that to be inserted in the options field. my final result now look like this
[image: preview]

please help me.

Comment: Share your SQL Query, that could help us determine what is going wrong...

Comment: add `WHERE col IS NOT NULL` in the where clause

Comment: Yup, JW nailed it in fact, don't even need to see the SQL :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   if($row['Series'] != '' || $row['Series'] != NULL) {
       $series1 .= "<option id='Series1' value='" . $row['Series'] ."'>" . $row['Series'] ."             </option>";
   }
}
```

OR

In your sql query

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE Series IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

```
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if(isset($row['Series'])) {
   $series1 .= "<option id='Series1' value='" . $row['Series'] ."'>" . $row['Series'] ."             </option>";
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<select id="Series1"  onchange="changeVal('Series1')">
    <option value="">Please select</option>


    <?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    if($row['Series'] != '' || $row['Series'] != NULL) 
     {
?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['Series']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Series']; ?></option>  
</select>



<?php
     }
}
?>
```